# how to add picture on above text

Tags: html, css

how I put a picture on top the hyperlinks  like in the middle and I want to put two text  between the picture  above the hyperlinks  but I   try it, but its always going on top the orange bar how I do code this so it goes  in front the orange bar? Thanks.

```css
   
        
        #nav {
        width: 110%;
            height: 150px;
          float: left;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: darkorange;
         }
        #nav li {
        float: left; }
           
        #nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 55px 55px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #069;
            margin-right: 284px;
           padding-top: 105px;
            font-size: 25px
         }
        #nav li a: {
        color: blue;
        background-color: darkorange; }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Malta Youth Group</title>
        </head>

    
    <div>
       <img id = "Logo"src="campfire1.png" alt="campfire logo" height="42" width="42">
        <div>   
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lastest activties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">How to join</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle and preferable a reference to how you want it to look like

Comment: https://www.google.com.mt/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1EJFA_enMT766MT766&biw=1920&bih=974&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=qKb0WuCsFszN6QSSzoTQDg&q=navigation+bar++wirh+logo+on+top+&oq=navigation+bar++wirh+logo+on+top+&gs_l=img.3...11997.18426.0.18781.25.22.2.0.0.0.140.2269.3j18.21.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.5.453...0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i8i30k1j0i24k1.0.hceMDjmR-WI#imgrc=chQ6nFvMp-O1pM: like this

Comment: but with pic on top of hyperlinks and in front of the orange bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure is this what you want to do, but let's try this:

```css
   #nav {
    width: 110%;
        height: 150px;
      float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: darkorange;
     }
    #nav li {
    float: left; }

    #nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 55px 55px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
        margin-right: 284px;
       padding-top: 105px;
        font-size: 25px
     }
    #nav li a: {
    color: blue;
    background-color: darkorange; 
    }
    img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 75px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
   <img id ="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="campfire logo" height="42" width="42">
    <div>   
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lastest activties</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How to join</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```